# Probability Question - What is the probability that it will rain on the day of Marie's wedding

Tags: probability

Marie is getting married tomorrow, at an outdoor ceremony in the desert. In recent years, it has rained only $5$ days each year.

Unfortunately, the weatherman has predicted rain for tomorrow. When it actually rains, the weatherman correctly forecasts rain $90\%$ of the time. When it doesn't rain, he incorrectly forecasts rain $10\%$ of the time.

What is the probability that it will rain on the day of Marie's wedding?

Comment: It looks obvious.  Probability of rain is 90%.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Do not confuse the probability that the forecaster accurately predicted rain given that rain actually occurs (*written below as $Pr(F\mid R)$*) with the probability that rain actually occurs given that the forecaster predicts it will come (*written below as $Pr(R\mid F)$*).

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ represent the event that he forecasted rain will occur.  Let $R$ represent that rain actually occurs.

We are told the following information:

$Pr(F\mid R)=0.9$ (*if it rained, the forecaster predicted it correctly 90% of the time*)

$Pr(F\mid R^c)=0.1$ (*if it didn't rain, the forecaster incorrectly predicted it should have rained 10% of the time*)

We are also likely intended to assume that $Pr(R)=\dfrac{5}{365}$ as per the phrase "*in recent years it has rained only 5 days each year*" or perhaps $Pr(R)=\dfrac{5}{365.25}$ or some other similar number according to how much you wish to account for leap year.  For simplicity's sake, I would suggest using $\dfrac{5}{365}$.

We are tasked with calculating $Pr(R\mid F)$.

Now... with this information we can apply Bayes' theorem:

$$Pr(R\mid F)=\dfrac{Pr(F\mid R)Pr(R)}{Pr(F)}$$

The terms in the numerator were given directly in the problem.  The term in the denominator can be calculated using the law of total probability and conditional probability:

$Pr(F)=Pr(F\cap R)+Pr(F\cap R^c)=Pr(R)Pr(F\mid R)+Pr(R^c)Pr(F\mid R^c)$

Plug in the appropriate numbers and reach a final conclusion.